# Listagg() with distinct and order by

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need help in getting below result in Snowflake

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | CAR |
| 456 | BUS |
| 789 | CYCLE |
| 123 | CAR |
| 789 | CYCLE |

Expected Result

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 123,456,789 | CAR,BUS,CYCLE |

tried with:

```
Select
  listagg(distinct Code,',') within group (order by Code ) as Code,
  listagg(distinct Description,',') within group (order by Description) as Description
from table
```

But not getting code and description in respective order.

Comment: In my case, I have to use distinct with listagg function as the description is coming from the master table(no duplicates) but the main table has multiple codes. So I would need order by with distinct

Answer (score 2):

Both `Code` and `Description` are sorted independently inside `LISTAGG`. To keep `Code` with respective `Description` additional sort column could be used:

```
SELECT listagg(Code,',') within group (order by rn) as Code, 
   listagg(Description,',') within group (order by rn) as Description 
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Code, Description) AS rn
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code, Description FROM tab)) AS sub;
```

For source data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(CODE INT, DESCRIPTION TEXT)
AS 
SELECT 123 ,'CAR' UNION ALL
SELECT 456 ,'BUS' UNION ALL
SELECT 789 ,'CYCLE' UNION ALL
SELECT 123 ,'CAR' UNION ALL
SELECT 789 ,'CYCLE';
```

Output:

| CODE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 123,456,789 | CAR,BUS,CYCLE |

Comment: You don't even need `rn`, you could `order by code, description` directly in `listagg`.

Comment: @GMB Thank you for suggestion.  I have also considered it, but it is NOT possible to use columns inside ORDER BY that are not part of LISTAGG + DISTINCT:
 `LISTAGG(DISTINCT Code, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Code /*Description*/)`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqL5.png

Comment: I was thinking of something like this: `select listagg(code, ',') within group (order by code, description) codes from (select distinct code, description from mytable) t`

Comment: @GMB That alternative is a feasible one.

Comment: In my case, I have to use distinct with listagg function as description is coming from the master table(no duplicates) but the main table has multiple codes